# ¿Como generar mi apk luego de finalizado mi aplicación en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Estoy terminando mi aplicación de android y quiero probarla en otros celulares, pero cuando genero la apk y la instalo en otro móvil, la aplicación se instala pero no inicia, alguien me puede decir que tener en cuenta para generar la apk y que me funcione en otros celulares, la he probado en celulares con mi misma versión de android y nada. Aquí les dejo el código del archivo manifest por si es aquí donde falla.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LIst_Cumple"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list__cumple" />
    <activity
        android:name=".adicionar"
        android:label="adicionar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".modificar"
        android:label="modificar" />

    <service
        android:name=".service.service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".InicService" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="alarma1"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>





</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"/>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: Como la estas generando? Que pasos das para generarla?

Comment: lo probaste con el emulador? sino la otra que podes hacer es conectar el celu a la pc y lo probas directamente, no hace falta que generes el apk

Comment: si lo he provado con el emulador y compilando con mi propio movil ,pero al generar la apk y probarlo en otro movil con las mismas prestaciones que el mio se instala pero se sierra en cuano abres la aplicacion

Comment: estoy generando la apk mediante Build/generate signed apk

Comment: Prueba quitando `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"/>`

Comment: probé quitando <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"/> y el problema persiste

Answer (score 0):

Debes comentar el error que te envía el logcat. Antes de compilar prueba en un emulador

si al iniciar escribes en la memoria externa, tienes que solicitar los permisos en tiempo de ejecucion, aparte de haberlo declarado en el archivo Manifest. esto para versiones android posteriores al 6.0 puedes ver el ejemplo https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html